CS0029 error when returning NotFound() method in controller function
How do I handle this error in a controller function?
I get CS0029 error when returning NotFound() method...
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<Database?> GetById(string id)
    {
        var response = await _databasesService.GetById(id);

        var database = response.FirstOrDefault();

        if (database is not null)
            return database;
        else
            return NotFound(); // Error CS0029
    }



Your method is returning a nullable Database, why would you expect to be able to return a NotFound instead? This has nothing to do with null handling.

You could try making the method return type Task<ActionResult<Database>> instead.

@DavidG The error is gone, still I get an error in the response body. I Edited the question... I'm using Supabase for database...

You can't just keep changing the question, I answered the original. If you have other problems, then make a new post.

If you want to replace the Format Exception with a NotFound use an Exception Block surround the call to your databaseService, check the Exception and do the proper thing in the catch block.

Where is the null exception you talk about?

@Ralf There was never a null exception, in fact there wasn't any exception, it was just a compiler error that OP confused, I guess because they are returning a nullable value(?)

@DavidG
You're right. I'll make a new post... Thanks!

Make sure the new post contains only relevant information and is a [mre], that error you talk about seems to be inside the GetById method.

Your method is expecting a return type of Database? type, so you can't cast a NotFound object to that. To fix this, change your method signature to return a Task<ActionResult<Database>>, for example:
public async Task<ActionResult<Database>> GetById(string id)
{
   ...
}


Also mind: var database = response.FirstOrDefault(); is another source for possible NRE. Should probably be var database = response?.FirstOrDefault();.

@Fildor Sure, but there are so many things wrong with the original code that I didn't think it was worth bringing up. Like, GetById shouldn't even be returning an enumerable in the first place!

Agreed. Also, OP changing the question after it has been answered is ... confusing for later readers (like me).
